# NLFFI: DynLinkage.open_lib raises DynLinkError

Tags: sml, ffi, smlnj

I'm exploring NLFFI ([No Longer Foreign Function Interface](http://mlton.org/References#Blume01)), its implementation in SML/NJ. The "math" example works, but "pdb" gives an error:

> FFI/pdb.cm:53.5-53.21 Error: link-time exception in user program
>   (pdb.cm):FFI/(pdb.cm):../pdbhandle.sml
>   DynLinkErrornlffi/lib/memory/linkage-dlopen.sml:67.26-67.40
>
> /usr/lib/smlnj/bin/sml: Fatal error -- Uncaught exception Link with
>   0  raised at ../cm/compile/link.sml:357.28-357.35

My shared library gives the same error. I think that the error is in "pdbhandle.sml" where dynamic linking goes, because "math" links the SML/NJ runtime library `DynLinkage.main_lib` and "pdb" links its own library. I tried to load the library manually:

```
sml -m "\$c/internals/c-int.cm"
```

and

```
DynLinkage.open_lib { name = "./pdb.so", global = true, lazy = true };
```

I get

> uncaught exception DynLinkError   raised at:
>   nlffi/lib/memory/linkage-dlopen.sml:67.26-67.40

```
DynLinkage.open_lib { name = "/usr/lib/libgmp.so.10.2.0", global =
true, lazy = true };
```

gives the same error.

```
$ ls -l /usr/lib/libgmp.so.10.2.0
```

> -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 488208 бер 26 01:03 /usr/lib/libgmp.so.10.2.0

I see that `DynLinkError` has an argument, but SML/NJ does not show it. (BTW, is it a normal behavior?) I'm stuck here because I don't know what the error message is.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that I was linking a library for the x86_64 architecture, but SML/NJ is x86-program. (I'm using ArchLinux x86_64 Multilib.)

```
DynLinkage.open_lib { name = "/usr/lib32/libgmp.so.10.2.0"
    , global = true, lazy = true };
```

works.

I print an argument of an exception by an ugly expression

```
(DynLinkage.open_lib { name = lib_file_name, global = true, lazy = true }
    ; raise Div)
    handle DynLinkage.DynLinkError x => x;
```